# I tried resetting my MySQL password through command prompt but it is showing an error

Tags: mysql

I want to reset my MySQL password as I don't remember it. I followed the steps provided [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). However, I am unable to reset my password.
My MySQL version is 8.0.26.

I tried the following code in the **command prompt** (**Administrative Mode**):

```
C:\Windows\System32>cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.ini" --init-file="C:\\mysql-init.txt" --console
```

The output that I got:

```
2023-03-24T07:21:30.737856Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2023-03-24T07:21:30.739804Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 17616
2023-03-24T07:21:30.764005Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013907] [InnoDB] Deprecated configuration parameters innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group have been used to compute innodb_redo_log_capacity=100663296. Please use innodb_redo_log_capacity instead.
2023-03-24T07:21:30.791823Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-03-24T07:21:31.002695Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 8.0.26, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html
2023-03-24T07:21:31.003512Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-03-24T07:21:31.040737Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-03-24T07:21:31.044728Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-03-24T07:21:31.045692Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-03-24T07:21:31.050695Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I tried going through `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html`. But it didn't helped. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you using a different mysqld version than your data was created with?  install 8.0.26 and try that?

Comment: Use generic instructions. I.e. start MySQL server service with the `--skip-grant-tables` option (ensure that it is started successfully!) then reset the password from CLI.